# Replace "<?php print t('Blabla'); ?>" to be "Blabla"

Tags: command-line, sed, replace

Lets say in `file.php`, there is lots of php print text: `<?php print t('Blabla'); ?>`, `<?php print t('Text Here'); ?>`, etc.

What I need is to remove `<?php print t('` and `'); ?>` of the php print text.

So, `<?php print t('Blabla'); ?>` will become `Blabla`, `<?php print t('Text Here'); ?>` will become `Text Here`, etc.

If one php print text in one line, I think I know how to use `sed` to replace, but how about if one long line contains several php print text

I just wonder how to replace it?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you add a `g` at the end of the `sed` command, it tries to match multiple occurences on the same line. `sed 's/bladibla-As-Is/bladibla-To-Be/g`'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I know about the `g`. I just wonder (if can) single line command that will remove `<?php print t('` and `'); ?>` of the php print text. (Question updated. Hope it will be easier to understand)

Comment: Why not just execute the php script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your intention is to remove an old internationalization system from your PHP scripts.

```
perl -e 'undef$/;$s=<>;$s=~s/<\?php\s+(?:print|echo)\s+t\((['"'"'"])(.*?)\1\);\s+\?>/$2/gs;print$s' apasajja
```

This has some improvements not asked in the question:

- Works for both `print` or `echo`.
- Works for both single and double quotes.
- Allows the `<?php` .. `?>` tags to be in separate lines.
- Allows t()'s parameter to span over several lines.

But there are still enough situations in which will fail.